# Nhibernate throws exception as 'Cannot instatiate abstract class or interface'

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have the following code,

```
IRepository<Profile> _repository;
var vendors = _repository.All();
```

To fetch the record for `Id 1271`. I have the below code and that throws the exception.

```
vendor ven = vendors.Where(e => e.Id == 1271).FirstOrDefault();
```

Please help me to understand what is going wrong here.

Comment: What is the declaration of the `Profile` class like? Is it abstract or lacking a public constructor?

Comment: Hi Martin,The profile class is declared as abstract.And it works fine for other ids except 1271

Comment: There are to many things to guess from your question for answering you. Please review [ask]. What does `IRepository<>.All`? Yielding a `IQueryable<>` from `ISession.Query<>` extension method? How is mapped `Profile`? Likely as an abstract base class for some others, and that id `1271` is probably lacking either a valid discriminator value or a row in a subclass table (if using TPC). You have to give a lot more details about your trouble, as your repository code and your classes mappings.

Comment: If `Profile` is abstract that would explain the error 'Cannot instatiate abstract class or interface'. Do queries for other Ids actually return an object, or do they return `null` (because those Ids do not exist)? My guess is that 1271 is found, and it then tries to create an instance of `Profile`, which it cannot as it is abstract.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(vendors.Where(e=>e.Id==1271).count()>0)
{
// put your code.. here 
}
```

Comment: I tried this but didn't work.The if condition is passed but getting the error.

Comment: check with .contains()

Comment: Sorry.I Could not understand this.

Comment: vendors.contains("The value")

Comment: If I am not wrong vendors.contains() can be used for String type only right?.And Vendors is a user defined object type.